# How can I wrap long text in (js bootstrap react) dynamically created table cell which is input type?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I dynamically created an online table with node js in which some cells are for text input i.e.

```
$tbody.append(`<tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>`);
```

I want to wrap long text similar to the Excel wrap function, I tried word-wrap, etc., seems not to apply to the input type.
If that's no possible then how about stretching column (width)? basically I want Excel like effect so some cells w/ long text can be visible.

Comment: For multi-line text you need to use `<textarea>` instead of `<input>`

Comment: Another option is to use the `contentEditable` attribute. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) for details.

Comment: thanks tromgy for your suggestions, well, I'm afraid that's not what I desired, the closest is text-overflow: ellipsis;  is there a way to see whole text by clicking something (ellipsis, triangle, etc.) inside that input cell?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to use an overlay. The content would be rendered in the cell without an `<input>` element. When the user clicks the cell (or a marker or whatever), an overlay that includes the content in an `<input>` is shown, aligned to the cell.

Comment: thanks Ouroborus, sounds interesting but you cannot input in overlay mode, right? well, if works then at least can solve half problem (can see long text but cannot edit in that mode)

Comment: forgot to mention that I'm using bootstrap and react (ejs) so comments by experts on those fields will be very much appreciated